# Django puts spaces in first Line of TextField

Tags: django, django-forms, prismjs

I'm creating a webapp where I can present a documentation. In my documentations I often have some code snippets so I used prism (https://prismjs.com/) to format the text I enter in a textfield on the admin page.

The Problem is that whenever I enter code in the textfield it makes spaces on the first line like that:

```
    import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';  
import { UserService } from '../user.service';
```

My code looks likt this:

**Template:**

```
<pre><code class="language-{{ subdoc.language }}">
        {{ subdoc.code }}            
</code></pre>
```

Comment: Your HTML is the culprit. Looks like you have space or tab characters right before `{{ subdoc.code }}`, since you're using `<pre>` tag, those space/tab characters won't disappear.

Comment: @xxbinxx OMG thanks I'm such a dumb ass xD. Can you write that as a answer so i can close the qestion?

Comment: If you have your answer, You can now close the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the spaces/tab characters before `{{ subdoc.code }}`

You must be exhausted in coding. Most of the time we think the complicated coding is where something's wrong but in your case it's the HTML.

you sure know how `<pre>` tag works. Now understand the difference between this

```
 <pre><code class="language-{{ subdoc.language }}">
        {{ subdoc.code }}            
 </code></pre>
```

and this

```
<pre><code class="language-{{ subdoc.language }}">
{{ subdoc.code }}            
</code></pre>
```

Happy coding ;)